# Division by zero laravel php 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have a percentage calculation. But if no data is available, I get the following error message:

> Division by zero

Calculation:

```
$count_progress = ($get_progress / $gc->jumlah_cek) * 100;
```

Comment: you should add full source code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'll be a good idea to check $gc->jumlah_cek parameter:

```
if ($gc->jumlah_cek != 0)
    $count_progress = ($get_progress / $gc->jumlah_cek) * 100;
else
    $count_progress = 0;
```